# Create Table within Tikz Node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create a flowchart with tikz and some nodes should include tables.
The end result should look similar to this:
[image]

I tried creating a table and including it in a node.
However simply adding it to the nodes content breaks formatting.
Code of the table:

```
\resizebox{3cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|>{\bfseries}c|}
\hline
{Hook}       &  {Policies} \\ \hline
{file\_open} &  {Pol1}     \\ \hline
{send\_pkt}  &  {Pol2}     \\ \hline
{...}        &  {...}      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

Unfortunately i couldn't find similar examples and i am not sure if
including the table in the text field is the right approach.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: you can use a `tabular` anywhere you can use text, if you get an error show the error message from the log and provide a small but complete document that shows the problem. (unrelated to tikz but avoid using `\resizebox` on tables, better to use a consistent font size such as `\small`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which indicate your issues, i.e. where you stuck at your effort to draw showed image. Because you not, looks that you looking for service "make-this-instead-me". Site is not intended for such services ...

Because it's the holidays now and you're a newbie ... see the following MWE which is based on guessing what is your problem ...

```
\documentclass[border=3.1314592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
       > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
    font = \sffamily]
\node (t)   [draw, align=center,
             label={[anchor=north east]north east:pollicy\_NS}]% 
{   \\[1.5\baselineskip]
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 cells  = {c},
                 row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries, rowsep=0pt}
                 }
Hook        &   Policies    \\
file\_open  &   Pol1        \\
send\_pkt   &   Pol2        \\
    \dots   &   \dots       \\
    \end{tblr}
};
\draw[<-, semithick, shorten <=-4pt]   ([yshift=+3pt] t.east) -- ++ (1,0);
\draw[->, semithick, shorten <=-4pt]   ([yshift=-3pt] t.east) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you. I added my code above and ironically just discovered the problem before your post. \tikzmark broke the table, i thought i had already tried it out without it but i must have made an error. Thank you for your solution, it works and i will accept it.

Comment: Actually i had already removed it. Tbh. i don't know what the problem was. I guess a matter of sitting at this problem for too long and a series of mistakes.